# How to handle an event in a child component that is fired from a dynamically created grandchild component?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura, lightning-events, platform-event, aura-handler

I have a component that includes a child component. The child component has a button that fires showCustomModal on an overlayLibrary and the content is a dynamically created component.

Component hierarchy:

```
Parent
    Child
        Grandchild (Dynamically created)
```

The grandchild has a button that fires a component event that should be handled in the child component. The event fires, but is **not** handled. However, if I **close** the modal and **re-open** it and then click the button again the event is both fired and handled.

Parent component

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes">
    <c:TestChild />
</aura:component>
```

Child Component

```
<aura:component >
    <aura:handler name="testEventName" event="c:TestEvent" action="{!c.handleTestEvent}" includeFacets="true"/>
    <aura:attribute name="overlay" type="Aura.Component[]" />
    <lightning:overlayLibrary aura:id="overlayLib"/>
    <lightning:button label="Open Modal" onclick="{!c.createComponent}" />
</aura:component>
```

Child Controller

```
({
    createComponent : function(component, event, helper) {
        $A.createComponent("c:TestGrandChild", 
            {
                testEventName: component.getReference('c.handleTestEvent'),
            },
            function(content, status, errorMessage) {
               if (status === "SUCCESS") {
                   component.find('overlayLib').showCustomModal({
                       header: "Test Title",
                       body: content, 
                       showCloseButton: true,
                   }).then(function (overlay) {
                        component.set('v.overlay', overlay);
                   })
                } 
            });
    },
    handleTestEvent : function(component, event, helper) {
        console.log('handled');
    }
})
```

Grandchild component

```
<aura:component >
    <aura:registerEvent name="testEventName" type="c:TestEvent" />
    <lightning:button label="Fire event" onclick="{!c.fireEvent}" />
</aura:component>
```

Grandchild controller

```
({
    fireEvent : function(component, event, helper) {
        var componentEvent = component.getEvent('testEventName');
        componentEvent.fire();
        component.destroy();
    },
})
```

Event

```
<aura:event type="COMPONENT" description="Test event" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try instead of using component.getEvent('testEventName') in your grandchild controller, use `event.getSource()`.

And then, when we handled the event in the parent component, we use `event.getSource` again.

Our example isn't directly related to yours, but here is the reference of how we are using it and it has been working whether it be in a dynamic component where it gets created with create component, or when it is being explicitly used in markup.

Event

```
<aura:event type="COMPONENT" description="Dispatched when a select has changed value">
    <aura:attribute name="values" type="String[]" description="Selected values" access="global" />
</aura:event>
```

The event getting registered on the child

```
<aura:registerEvent name="valueChange" type="c:SelectChange" />
```

The child component event method

```
handleChangeEvent : function(component, event) {
        var eventSource = event.getSource();
        var values = eventSource.get("v.value");
        var cmpEvent = component.getEvent("valueChange");
        cmpEvent.setParams({
            "values" : values
        });
        cmpEvent.fire();
    }
```

Handling the event on the parent

```
<aura:handler name="valueChange" event="c:SelectChange" action="{!c.handleEvent}" />
```

Then in the parent controller

```
handleEvent : function(component, event, helper) {
        var value = event.getParam("values");
        var item = event.getSource();
        item.set("v.value", value);
        component.set("v.validForm", helper.validateForm(component));
    },
```

Here is a link with more information on [Handling Events with Client Side Controllers](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_client_side_controller.htm).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! We ended up using application events, as this unfortunately did not solve our issue.